# Accessing template in a subfolder with Annotations

Tags: symfony, routes, annotations

I have a folder `ProjectFolder` with a subfolder `Mobile` and a template `indexMobile.html.twig` inside it.

```
AppBundle
  | Resources
    | views
      | ProjectFolder
        | Mobile
          - indexMobile.html.twig
        | someView.html.twig
        | someView.html.twig
        | someView.html.twig
```

In my controller I tried accessing it with various recommandation with [@Template doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/view.html) and [@route doc](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

But my different approaches didn't find my already created template, it keeps asking me to create a template in `views` directly instead of `Mobile` subfolder.

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
    /**
         * @Route("@Mobile/indexMobile")
         * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
         * @Template
         */
        public function indexMobileAction()
        {
            return[];
        }
```

-

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
    /**
         * @Route("/Mobile/indexMobile")
         * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
         * @Template
         */
        public function indexMobileAction()
        {
            return[];
        }
```

-

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
    /**
         * @Route("Mobile", name="indexMobile")
         * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
         * @Template
         */
        public function indexMobileAction()
        {
           return[];
        }
```

Actually this works but this is not the way I am supposed to use:

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
    /**
         * @Route("/mobile/index")
         * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
         * @Template("@ProjectFolder/Mobile/index.html.twig")
         */
        public function indexMobileAction()
        {
            return[];
        }
```

**EDIT**

After some tries I found this:

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
/**
     * @Route("@ProjectFolder/Mobile", name="/mobile/index")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexMobileAction()
    {
        return[];
    }
```

But I get this error: `No route found for "GET/mobile/index"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You provided the right solution in this example:

```
class ProjectFolderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/mobile/index")
     * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
     * @Template("@ProjectFolder/Mobile/index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexMobileAction()
    {
        return[];
    }
}
```

The logic used by default by `@Template` to find the templates doesn't support subdirectories. That's why you must pass the template path as a parameter of `@Template`.

Using Twig namespaces should be easy. Example: `@Template("@App/Mobile/index.html.twig")` finds the `src/AppBundle/Resources/views/index.html.twig` and `@Template("mobile/index.html.twig")` would find `app/Resources/views/mobile/index.html.twig` (and `templates/mobile/index.html.twig` in Symfony 4).

Comment: Thank you for your time explaining why @Template doesn't support subdirectories. Clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are missing here is that using @Template like this will by default use this to search it:

"AppBundle:NAME(Controller):indexMobile.html.twig"

So this Folder hierarchy will work:

```
AppBundle
 | Resources
   | views
       | Mobile
         - indexMobile.html.twig
```

Using MobileController like this:

```
class MobileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("Mobile/indexMobile")
     * @Template
     */
    public function indexMobileAction()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. Yeah I got the hint that `@Template` actually search by default. But couldn't actually use your answer to search in the subfolder. I still cannot find how to use it with `@Template` (I edited my question)